# Posts from Website to Facebook are not public

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post some content (like news etc.) from my website (PHP) to a Facebook fanpage (the fanpage of the website), so I use the Facebook PHP SDK.

It works but the posts on the FB fanpage are not public, only the admin (logged) can see it.

I did not find how/where to set the permissions in the Facebook Developpers's account. On the fanpage, the application visibility (in applications > parameters) is set to public. An access token has been generated with the following permissions (scope) : manage_pages, publish_stream, offline_access

When I generate the access token, the perms (in the array 'data'which is returned by Facebook) are :

```
[perms] => Array([0] => ADMINISTER 
                 [1] => EDIT_PROFILE 
                 [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                 [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                 [4] => CREATE_ADS
                 [5] => BASIC_ADMIN)
```

Thanks for your answers.

PS : I apologize for my english, I'm french.

Comment: are you in sandbox mode?

Comment: Yes, I think, "" in FB Developper's account under my application name

Comment: so this is the problem, turn off the sandbox mode and you should see all the posts as public!

Comment: Oops sorry for my previously comment... I send it too quickly. I've changed the status of my app to "public" and it works fine now. Thanks.